# linked list insertion operation and display

Tags: c, list

I am trying to implement a singly linked list and performing insertion operations.The program compiles and runs but whenever i try to display its elements.It doesn't show the elements.I am not able to find out the error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct n
{
    int data;
    struct n *next;
};

typedef struct n node;

node *insert_at_front(node *start,int info)
{
    node *temp,*p;
    temp=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->data=info;
    temp->next=start;
    start=temp;
    return start;
}

node *insert_at_end(node *start,int info)
{
    node *temp,*p;
    temp=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(start==NULL)
    {
        printf("Empty\n");
        return start;
    }
    else
    {
        for(p=start; p->next!=NULL; p=p->next)
        {
            if(p->next==NULL)
            {
                temp->data=info;
                temp->next=p->next;
                p->next=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return start;
}

node *insert_after(node *start,int info,int dat)
{
    node *temp,*p;
    temp=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    for(p=start; p->next!=NULL; p=p->next)
    {
        if(p->data==dat)
        {
            temp->data=info;
            temp->next=p->next;
            p->next=temp;
        }
    }
    return start;
}

void display(node *start)
{
    node *temp;
    if(start==NULL)
    {
        printf("List is Empty\n");
        return ;
    }
    temp=start;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d-->",temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}

int main()
{
    int value;
    node *start=NULL;
    int choice,data1;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("\n1.insert_at_start\n2.insert at end.\n3.insert_after");
        printf("\n4.display\n");
        printf("enter choice\n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch(choice)
        {
        case 1:
            printf("Enter value\n");
            scanf("%d",&value);
            insert_at_front(start,value);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Enter value\n");
            scanf("%d",&value);
            insert_at_end(start,value);
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Enter value\n");
            printf("Enter value after which you want to insert\n");
            scanf("%d%d",&value,&data1);
            insert_after(start,value,data1);
            break;
        case 4:
            display(start);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. The current code doesn't compile.

Comment: Please also post details of what you found out during your own debugging.

Comment: What inputs did you give for testing?  What got printed out?  'It doesn't show the elements' is next-to-useless:(

Comment: The formatting/indenting needs work.  I cannot see where one function ends and the next begins.  'insert_after' looks like it's nested.  If you are goignto bother to post code to SO, please make it easily readable and is a version/copy that compiles.

Comment: the inputs were 1,3,5 and 7 and when i chose display option.I got list is empty as the output

Comment: Great!  Now fix thecode so that it, too, compiles.  Then run it under your debugger in the usual way and see what is happening when you insert just one item and try to print it.  If you still have problems, post code that compiles appended to your question above, or post another question.

Answer (score 1):

One problem with your code is that you're not using the return values from the different insert procedures. This means that if you start with an empty list (NULL) there is no way that `main` can get a non-empty list back.

At least you need to update `start`, for example:

```
start = insert_at_front(start,value);
```

Comment: I saw that. Seems 'odd' that the OP knew enough to return the modified start etc, but not enough to actually store it in main().  There again, the posted code does not even compile:(